# project loading issue

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have an issue while trying to load a C# project

```
var project = new Project(xmlProject, null, null, ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings.Default);
```

Failure - An equivalent project (a project with the same global properties and tools version) is already present in the project collection

What is the best way to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```
if (ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(xmlProject).Count == 0)
{
       var proj =
                    new Project(
                        xmlProject,
                        null,
                        null,
                        ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection,
                        ProjectLoadSettings.Default);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From a VS2015 cmd prompt: "devenv /resetuserdata"

Answer (score 1):

You can unload the project after working with it:

```
ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.UnloadProject(project);
```

Or you check the loaded projects:

```
ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(projectFilePath)
```